# Multiple colors for single path Android

Tags: android, canvas, path, draw

Good day.I am creating a siri like wave for android and i encounter an big issue.I need the wave to be in 4 colors.Lets assume i only have one single line which is drawing on the screen accordingly to the voice decibels.Anyway i am able to do it but no way i am able to give 4 different colors for same path.Assume it is 1 single path which moves from screen start to screen end,i need that line to have 4 different colors,mainly i had to divide the path into 4 parts and draw the color for each parts,but neither google,nor any other source give me anything (not even found anything similar to what i want).
Meanwhile i am posting the code where actually i am drawing the lines.

```
    for (int l = 0; l < mWaveCount; ++l) {
            float midH = height / 2.0f;
            float midW = width / 2.0f;

            float maxAmplitude = midH / 2f - 4.0f;

            float progress = 1.0f - l * 1.0f / mWaveCount;
            float normalAmplitude = (1.5f * progress - 0.5f) * mAmplitude;

            float multiplier = (float) Math.min(1.0, (progress / 3.0f * 2.0f) + (1.0f / 3.0f));

            if (l != 0) {
                mSecondaryPaint.setAlpha((int) (multiplier * 255));
            }

            mPath.reset();
            for (int x = 0; x < width + mDensity; x += mDensity) {
                float scaling = 1f - (float) Math.pow(1 / midW * (x - midW), 2);
                float y = scaling * maxAmplitude * normalAmplitude * (float) Math.sin(
                        180 * x * mFrequency / (width * Math.PI) + mPhase) + midH;
//                canvas.drawPoint(x, y, l == 0 ? mPrimaryPaint : mSecondaryPaint);
//
//                canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, 2*midH - y, mSecondaryPaint);


                if (x == 0) {
                    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                } else {
                    mPath.lineTo(x, y);
//                    final float x2 = (x + mLastX) / 2;
//                    final float y2 = (y + mLastY) / 2;
//                    mPath.quadTo(x2, y2, x, y);
                }

                mLastX = x;
                mLastY = y;
            }


            if (l == 0) {
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPrimaryPaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mSecondaryPaint);
            }
        }
```

I tried to change color on  `if (l == 0) {
                    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPrimaryPaint);
                }` but if i change it here,no result at all,either the line is separate and not moving at all,but it should,either the color is not applied,propably because i am doing it in loop as i had to and everytime the last color is picked to draw.Anyway can you help me out?Even an small reference is gold for me because really there is nothing at all in the internet.

Comment: Is you tried to single path with multicolor?

Comment: ummm how that achieved?that what i am actually asking....

Comment: i need exactly that!

Comment: if you tried to draw same path means why you use `.mPath.reset()`?? try to remove it

Comment: if i do not use reset,million of pathes will be drawn on the screen

Comment: if you use `reset()` means , the path will be drawn in new basis. then how do you see color change?

Comment: that the issue i need reset as in that loop it is over,it is all done,i am doing new path with new formats,otherwise million of lines will be drawn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyway even though Matt Horst answer fully correct,i found the simplest and easiest solution...i never thought it would be so easy.Anyway if in world there is someone who need to make an path divided into multiple colors,here is what you can do

```
    int[] rainbow = getRainbowColors();
    Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, width, rainbow,
            null, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(90);
    shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
    mPrimaryPaint.setShader(shader);
```

Where `getRainbowColors()` is an array of colors you wish your line to have and `width` is the length of the path so the Shader knows how to draw the colors in right way to fit the length of path.Anyway .....easy isnt it?and pretty purged me a lot to get into this simple point.Nowhere in internet you could find only if you are looking for something completelly different,than you might come across this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you could set up one paint for each section, each with a different color. Then set up one path for each section too. Then as you draw across the screen, wherever the changeover point is between sections, start drawing with the new path. And make sure first to use moveTo() on the new path so it starts off where the old one left off.

Comment: hmm i know that logic but it is only logic,very hard to implement

Comment: but i guess you misunderstood it,does't this mean that a full line will be colored in one single color i specify,as the L is the loop of waves count,meaning each line which already must be drawn and not for each coordinate?meanwhile i need an single line to be colored in different colors

Comment: hmmm but the draw line is in the state where each coordinate is used,so it can help let me try anyway

Comment: Ah I see you are using lineTo on a single path and then at the end rendering that path? What if you actually make X paths (however many colors you want) and based on how far along the X you are, you call addLine() to only one of those X paths?

Comment: hmmmmm fairly it is interesting as it sounds but i did not understand a thing :D i mean i did not understand why to use the addLine and what it will actually do?

Comment: Oops sorry I meant: mPath.lineTo(x, y); That is, instead of just having 1 path for each wave you wanted to draw, you'd have 4 (or whatever). Then assuming you want to split into 4 colors, you'd have 4 different paths. And based on the total x / 4, you'd evaluate the current x you are at, and you'd use .lineTo() on whichever of the paths you needed. Then you'd render each path with a different paint (which has the different color).

Comment: oopsie now that sounds great let me do that :) this one i cant do becase it is inside the loop which loops based on widht so imagine..it is laggy,so ill try this last one see what i can do,gimme a moment :)

Comment: Ok. Definitely I'd say to make sure you define all the Paint and Path objects outside the loop, so the only thing you are doing inside the loop is clearing the path each time (like you are now but clearing all 4) and then doing the actual render.

Comment: shit...forgot....If i draw with x/4 and with lineTo you will remember that the drawPath has start and end points ofcourse right?So imagine yourself an wave,the wave starts and the wave ends,i draw x/4 and at the end the point just being still there like something holding it,so no matter if i continue from the x/4 point,the previous one will seems attached by the air and wont be waved within the following line...damn this

Comment: Oh, at the changeover point use moveTo() to move the new line to where the former line ends. Like: if (changeOver) { oldPath.lineTo(x, y); newPath.moveTo(x, y);} else { path.lineTo(x, y); } In other words, if its not the changeover point, just draw old path line to as normal. But if changeover point, draw old path lineTo() AND next path moveTo(), so the new path will then start where the old path left off. Or probably because of this you'd want "is changeover" logic to basically be 1 x region BEFORE the actual changeover point you want because you'll be drawing one last path at old color.

Answer (score 1):

For my solution, I tried changing the color of the linePaint in the onDraw Call. But it was drawing a single color.

So i used two different paints for two different colors and draw path on the canvas.

And it worked. Hope it helps someone out there.